# iOS 13 crash on launch

Tags: ios, crash, ios13

With iOS 13.0 update, app is crashing on launch. Users are reporting that app is crashing on fresh start.

I receive this from Crashlytics:

Just after, `[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` is calling `viewDidLoad:` on a ViewController that it is used just very later on app flow, or maybe never.

What is very strange with it: - I can not reproduce, for every iPhone that I have under test, app is working just fine. It is not working for 10% of our users.

1. Could Crashlytics be wrong? - and it is reporting wrong, because Crashlytics is not initialized yet
2. The ViewController-s name where the error appears, it is "ViewController" - could this be a conflict? It seems that this one, it not initilized properly. 
   Into the viewDidLoad: I have this:

   `self.tabButtons = @[_btnOne, _btnSecond, _btnThird, _btnFourth];` - this line it is reported in Crashlytics with

   "Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]"
3. How could I reproduce?

Here is the code in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
...............................
    [self showFirstScreen];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}


-(void) showFirstScreen {
    NSInteger companyAddedGet = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"companyAdded"];
    (companyAddedGet == -1) ? [self showAddNewCompanyViewController] : [self login];
}

-(void) login {
    ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LOGIN_DETAIL"]!=nil) ? [self automaticLogin] : [self showLogin];
}

-(void) automaticLogin {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Launch Screen" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *launchScreen = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LaunchScreenVC"];
    nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:launchScreen];
    nav.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"login_automat" parameters: nil];
    [self fetchCompanyData];
}

-(void) showLogin {
    viewController = [[loginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"loginViewController" bundle:nil];
    nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    nav.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}

-(void) showAddNewCompanyViewController {
    .....
    AddNewCompanyVC *addNewVC = [[AddNewCompanyVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddNewCompanyVC" bundle:nil];
    [(AppObj).nav pushViewController:addNewVC animated:YES];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show `ViewController.m` around line 110.

Comment: ViewController line 110:  self.tabButtons = @[_btnOne, _btnSecond, _btnThird, _btnFourth].   ViewController is called after login, but just in some cases (1%).

Comment: one of those is `nil`.

Comment: ViewController is not called yet. So how could possible Crashlytics report something about it?

Comment: It's clearly in the call stack, so it has been called.

Comment: @trojanfoe, I'll put some more code, because I don't understand.

Comment: Could possibly be after IOS 13 something in one of those buttons are going unrecognized, so the buttons/button doesnt render and get added to the sel.tabButtons (assuming its a stackview) so i think you should goto those buttons and see which one is not getting returned/created .

One thing is to check what font the buttons are using , IOS 13 might not be compatible with previous fonts in some cases which could result in the button failing to be rendered. Hence why only in some cases you are getting this error

Comment: Font is system in the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this: ( I don't modify the question - but I'll put here my solution).

- app did not used the initial viewcontroller declared in the Main.storyboard, because every vc was initialized on the moment needed. Which was good. But Main.storyboard declared was not needed. Also the initial view controller.
- the initial VC used, was ..... "suprise" .... the ViewController, where the err appears.

Also, none of the UITests started, because of this. I did not understood why.